# ADB: Running as an app on a rooted device in a release build

Tags: android, adb, root

I want to write files to an app's data/data/[package name] folder from adb, and to have that app read those files.

I know that on debug builds I can use the `run-as [package name]` command to run as that app and write the files as mentioned above.

When I run the above command on a release build, I get `run-as: Package '[package name]' is not debuggable`.

Is there a way to overcome this issue on a **rooted device** without setting debuggable=true?